# Toad for Mysql Server - Bad Handshake error when connecting to remote host

Tags: mysql, sql, toad, ssh-keys

I am not able to connect to my remote server using Toad and get a Bad Handshake error.

Now I know that it is because the ssh public key has changed on the server but I cannot find where this is configured in Toad and how I can delete the key.

Would anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you can connect to the server administrator's cpanel, add your ip to the mysql remote list, under mysql remote. Keep in mind, if you don't have a static ip this can suddenly stop working when your isp changes your ip

2) Check and make sure you have the correct address for the mysql server. In cpanel this is usually on the left hand side. Mine was listed as box999.bluehost.com (or something along those lines)

3) Make sure your anti-virus isn't blocking the connection.

4) Make sure your sql client has mysql libraries enabled.